# How can I capture selected text in a pdf-view buffer with org-capture?

Tags: org-capture, pdf

I would like to capture the selected text (selected with the mouse) in a PDF document (opened in  PDFView Mode) with an org capture template.

When I evaluate the expression `(car (pdf-view-active-region-text))` with `eval-expression`, I can get this highlighted text.

However when I try to use it in a capture template like this:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("j" "Notes" entry (file+olp "~/Documents/wiki/Notes.org" "Notes")
         "* %?\n%(car (pdf-view-active-region-text))\n")))
```

I get:

```
** 
%![Error: (error The region is not active)]
```

I use the `pdf-tools` support library.

Comment: Have you tried `%i` or `%c` instead of `%(car (pdf-view-active-region-text))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the `*Capture*` buffer during the execution of the Elisp code embedded in the template.
Execute your code with the active buffer temporarily set to the original buffer. You get the original buffer from the plist variable `org-capture-plist` as property `:original-buffer`.

```el
(defun org-capture-pdf-active-region ()
  "Capture the active region of the pdf-view buffer."
  (let* ((pdf-buf-name (plist-get org-capture-plist :original-buffer))
         (pdf-buf (get-buffer pdf-buf-name)))
    (if (buffer-live-p pdf-buf)
        (with-current-buffer pdf-buf
          (car (pdf-view-active-region-text)))
      (user-error "Buffer %S not alive." pdf-buf-name))))

(setq org-capture-templates
      '(
        ("j" "Notes" entry (file+olp "/temp/Notes.org" "Notes")
         "* %?\n%(org-capture-pdf-active-region)\n")
        )
      )
```